# ajax login form, does not execute PHP event

Tags: php, ajax

I have an ajax function that should be able to log me in, the function is executing and if I firebug it, every thing seems ok.

the php event handler, is also working since i used form post method before, but would like to use ajax now, Any body see where the problem is ?

Ajax function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').click(function() { 
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();

        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'core/manage_articles.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {

                login:email,
                email:email,
                password:password,

            },
                success: function() {
                window.location = 'profile.php';
                }
        });
    });
});
```

and the eventlistner.

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) /*Login -two arguments.*/
{   
$email = $_POST['login_email'];
$password = $_POST['login_password'];
 ... all login stuff.
}
```

Comment: You are sending email:email,
                password:password, but you are listening to $_POST['login_email'] and $_POST['login_password'], you should listen to same variables names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_POST['login_email'] doesn't match your data. Should be $_POST['email']. Same with password.